# Quartz.NET remoting - scheduler already exists

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am creating an application that uses Quartz.NET, which is utilised within a Windows service. There is also an administration backend written in ASP.NET, where administrators can add jobs and monitor the state of the scheduler. I am however having issues with the ASP.NET backend.

The connection is made in the Global.asax file, which seems to work at first - when the user logs on to the main dashboard, it works fine. The problem is when the user clicks onto a different page, where it then says the scheduler 'schedService' already exists.

Here is my Windows Service code:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "schedService";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = threadcount;
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";

//
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.port"] = "555";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName"] = "QuartzScheduler";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType"] = "tcp";

//
// if running MS SQL Server we need thisl
properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

// config file
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = connection;
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";

ISchedulerFactory schedService = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = schedService.GetScheduler();
```

ASP.NET Global.asax code:

```
public static IScheduler Sched()
{
    NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

    properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "schedMaintenanceService";

    properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
    properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://localhost:555/QuartzScheduler";

    ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
    return sched;
}
```

Then I use this in each ASP.NET page:

```
public static IScheduler sched = Project.Global.Sched();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write your IScheduler as a singleton

Comment: Thanks - how would I go about doing this though? I found some code online but does this go in the client or the server, and how would I utilize this?

Comment: You should move both scheduler factory and scheduler as static class variables in Global.asax and initialize them only once. Say application_start.

Comment: Be wary of the application recycling and your scheduler thus being destroyed.

Comment: I am also getting similar problem. can you explain why do we need to move Ischeduler to a singleton class. In my appp , I need to create thousands of jobs in a day, i am bit worrried of the load on singleton class.

Comment: Everybody just keeps saying you should use Singleton but I cannot find a single solution for it. I have used Tarun Arora's solution (http://bit.ly/1xuVys0) but I keep receiving the same error. This is a solution that is claiming it already is using singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the "scheduler already exists". I created a singleton class and I was able move past my issue.

The singleton code looks like this if anybody can use it. The lock is to avoid the issue from before when having more threads trying to get the same instance at once.

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace MyProject.CommonObjects.Utilities
{
  public static class QuartzFactory
  {
    private static object _locker = new object();
    private static IScheduler _schedulerInstance;

    public static IScheduler SchedulerInstance
    {
      get
      {
        lock (_locker)
        {
          if (_schedulerInstance == null)
            _schedulerInstance = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

          return _schedulerInstance;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. By giving each scheduler a different name I was able to work around the issue. I find this a better solution than the singleton one.

```
  NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection
  {
    [StdSchedulerFactory.PropertySchedulerInstanceName] = "MyNewScheduler1"
  };
  StdSchedulerFactory fac = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
  _scheduler = fac.GetScheduler();
  _scheduler.Start();
```