# does the .config file configuration without <xml> node?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am configuration a qutartz.config file in visual studio 2010,but the content is like this:

```
01.# You can configure your scheduler in either <quartz> configuration section  
02.# or in quartz properties file  
03.# Configuration section has precedence  
04.  
05.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ServerScheduler  
06.  
07.# configure thread pool info  
08.quartz.threadPool.type = Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz  
09.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10  
10.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = Normal  
11.  
12.# job initialization plugin handles our xml reading, without it defaults are used  
13.quartz.plugin.xml.type = Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz  
14.quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames = ~/quartz_jobs.xml  
15.  
16.# export this server to remoting context  
17.quartz.scheduler.exporter.type = Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz  
18.quartz.scheduler.exporter.port = 555  
19.quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName = QuartzScheduler  
20.quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType = tcp  
21.quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName = httpQuartz
```

Can i paste it in .config file?

the config file normal like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

..............
```

How could i deal it? And make it work......

PS: qutartnet not qutart in java.

Comment: I would go with some key/value pair in the appsettings sections of the .config file and then load them in the code behind.

Comment: @FloChanz could you tell me how to? And where should i find

Comment: I guess it would be like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594742/quartz-net-remoting-scheduler-already-exists?rq=1
You can use the AppSettings section of you config file and retrieve each values in your code-behind with the ConfigurationManager of System.Configuration namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just copy-paste this settings, because xml configuration for Quartz Scheduler has different (xml) format:

```
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" 
       value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />  
       value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="quartz_jobs.xml" />
  ...
</quartz>
```

Comment: I've configurate this file,but how Quartz  find my configuration file?I think is this:14.quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames = ~/quartz_jobs.xml

Comment: Where and how could the program searching the <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="quartz_jobs.xml" /> this file?quartz_jobs.xml  My app.config do not contain a <quartz> schema